# Using batch script, write a text at a particular column of every line in a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Suppose i want to write a text "Check" at the 2000 position(column) and at every row of a text file using batch script.

Even the file contains the lines that ends at offset 100 or less than 2000.

According to me the algo could be...

1. A for loop  goes till end of rows starting from 1st position
2. Inner for loop to traverse to the col number(offset) without doing anything to the original file or if there is no text adding spaces to reach at that offset
3. if the offset is reached just add the text...and continue to the next line.

I hope i have cleared my question. Please help me to write it.
Thank You
Samrat Garai

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you have trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM build a 2000-space-char-string: 
for /l %%a in (1,1,2000) do set "spc=!spc! "
REM process every line [use a little trick to process empty lines also]
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" test.txt') do (
  REM append the long string to the line...
  set line=%%b!%spc%
  REM ... and cut to 2000 chars, appending "Check":
  echo(!line:~0,2000!Check
)
```

a quicker method to build a 2047 char string (the extra 47 chars do no harm here):

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do set "spc=!spc! !spc!"
```

the "little trick" to process also empty lines: `find /n` adds line numbers (like `[15]this is line no 15`) , so the line isn't empty any more. The second token (`*`= "rest of the line") after `]` is the original line.

Comment: The problem that is occuring, its deleting some data from the file.

Can u explain the trick ....?

Comment: Yeah Stephan, there are exclamation marks. Like "ABC DEF!$".

Comment: And there is one more thing, if i change the number to 25000. The input is too long error is coming. What should i do?..

Thanx Stephan

Comment: ´cmd` strings have a limit of a bit more than 8000 chars. So if you need more than that, you will have to use a different language. Handling the exclamation marks would be possible but very slow. Another reason for a different language...